# Initialization of wxColourDataBase while creating a new wxColourPickerCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

This is my first question ever posted, so please let me know if there is anything that needs changes in my post :)

I am currently working on a dialog that is supposed to let the user change the background-color for some signal plotting. The "wxColourPickerCtrl" seems to do exactly what I need. Since there are multiple plots/pictures to be manipulated, the ColourPickerCtrls are initialized in a loop with the chosen background color as the default value:

```
for (const auto& [signalName, signalProperties] : properties)
{
    wxColourPickerCtrl* selectBackgroundColor = new wxColourPickerCtrl(this, signalProperties.first, signalProperties.second.backgroundColor, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
}
```

"this" is an object of type SignalPropertiesDialog, which is directly inherited from wxDialog.
I have left out all the necessary sizer stuff, since it's not relevant for the problem (at least imo). "properties" is structured as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, GraphPicture::Properties>> signalProperties_;
```

where *GraphPicture::Properties* contains the properties I want to manipulate:

```
struct Properties
{
    wxColour backgroundColor{ *wxWHITE };
    wxColour lineColor{ *wxBLACK };
    int linewidth_px{ 1 };
    bool isShown{ true };
};
```

The application successfully builds but immediately crashes on startup while generating those color picker objects.

wxIshiko has uploaded multiple tutorials and code snippets as examples for various wxWidgets controls, including the wxColourPickerCtrl. So I downloaded the sample code and tried to run it. Surprisingly, it worked.

While running through the code step by step I noticed the following difference:

The wxColourPickerCtrl is based on wxPickerBase. The wxPickerBase is created by calling the constructor of wxColourPickerCtrl (what I am actually doing in my code). During the construction of the wxPickerBase, the desired color is called by the name `wxColourDataBase::FindName(const wxColour& color) const` where the wxColourBase itself is instantiated. This is where the difference is:

- When running the code snippet by wxIshiko, wxColourDataBase is instantiated correctly including the member `m_map` of type `wxStringToColourHashMap*` which is set to be `NULL`.
- When running the code written by myself, wxColourDataBase is not correctly instantiated, and thus the member `m_map` is not set to be `NULL`, which leads to to the crash.

I have the feeling that there is nothing wrong with the way I set up the wxColourPickerCtrls. I somehow think there is a difference in the solution properties of the projects. I checked those but was not able to find any relevant differences.

I would really appreciate any hint or help since I am completely stuck on that problem.

Thank you very much in advance and have a good one,

Alex

EDIT:
I attached a screeny of the call stack.

[Call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQVX.png)

Comment: `wxColourPickerCtrl* selectBackgroundColor` is a local variable inside the `for` loop. Is that how you intended? Do you save those pointers somewhere else in the real code, or do you lose them, and incorrectly attempt to access them later?

Comment: @catalin Yes, that's intended. I just need to know the specific ID for each `wxColourPickerCtrl*` to map those to the signal I want to manipulate. wxWidgets will handle the pointer deletion as soon as the parent will be destroyed.

Comment: @AlexanderWilbrandt, you don't need to know the ID's of the controls. Use dynamic event bindings, or inherit from the colour picker.

Comment: @Igor that's absolutely true. Imho, this has unfortunately nothing to do with the solution of the posted problem though.

Comment: @AlexanderWilbrandt, can you show the backtrace at the time of crash? for that you have to have debug build of the library and your code

Comment: @Igor I uploaded a screeny of the call stack at time instance of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

When does this code run exactly? If it is done after the library initialization (which would be the case, for example, for any code executed in your overridden `wxApp::OnInit()`), then `wxTheColourDatabase` really should be already initialized and what you observe should be impossible, i.e. if it happens it means that something is seriously wrong with your library build (e.g. it doesn't match the compiler options used when compiling your applications).

As always with such "impossible" bugs, starting with a known working code and doing bisection by copying parts of your code into the working version until it stops working will usually end up by finding a bug in your code.

Comment: The code is running after the library initialization. I am managing wxWidgets by using vcpkg though. Are there any known issues concerning this?